# SSIS run multiple steps side by side

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have some a job in SSIS that has 5 steps. The way it currently works is that it will go through the steps in order waiting for the previous one to be complete before doing the next. However with this job, steps 1-4 could all run at the same time with impacting the results of each other. So I was curious if it was possible to have steps 1-4 all run at the same time and once all are complete then start step 5.

I am open to the idea of doing this in other ways such as maybe having several different jobs, using triggers or anything else that will get the end result.

The main goal here is to have step 5 start as soon as possible but step 5 can not start until all 4 steps are done.

All of these steps are merely running a stored procedure to update a table.

I am using SQL 2012. I am very new to SSIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the Sequence Container tool is for.

You can put steps 1-4 in a Sequence Container and let them run in parallel in the container, and then have a Precedence Constraint from the container to Step 5.

Answer (score 0):

In your package set `MaxConcurrentExecutables` to.. say.. 6 and make sure there are no precedence constraints between your tasks.

Then they should run in parallel.

See here for more detail. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlperf/2007/05/11/implement-parallel-execution-in-ssis.

I'm curious - did you try googling this?